# My link doesnt work, when using ajax & jquery to open it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some `div` elements on my page. In the main `div`, content is loaded via AJAX using jQuery when links are clicked. This works perfectly when i click links that are not in the main `div`. But when I have a link in the main `div` that has been loaded via AJAX, they just don't work. I have no idea why. Here's an example:

I have a link. I gave it the class `products` so jQuery knows which content to load. So my link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="products">products</a>
```

I've put `href="javascript:;"` because for me `href="#"` doesn't work and I need a `href` so some CSS will work.

What can be the problem?

Comment: after ajax content load, just reassign the click event that you do on document ready.

Comment: How do you bind the click event on your links?

Comment: I was using `javascript:void(0);` in empty links.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your actual code I'm guessing, but more often that not problems like this are caused because you are assigning the `click` handler on load, and not re-assigning them when the new `div` elements are appended to the page.

To get around this use a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$('#parentDiv').on('click', 'a', function() {
    // do your thing in here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well, When you are putting `href="#"`, the page is actually reloads with the url being upended with # sign. you need to put **`return false`** at the end of click event to stop reloading and all will work fine. else you can do that in `href` as well.
How, that you need to find out I guess it has to be like `href="javascript:return false;"`

Comment: `the page is actually reloads with the url being upended with #` this is incorrect. No HTTP requests are made at all.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery API official suggest to all users to use `.live()` for this case,

Which the syntax like this:

```
$('a.products').live('click',function() {
   // do what you want
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Do you have a link for the page in the API which suggests this? You should report it as `live()` is now deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

the solution with .live worked for me.

here is the jquery code that i use now:

here is my code. sorry that i forgot to post it!

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sofas').live('click',function() {
    $('#content-shown , #pics').animate({opacity:0},250,function() {

    $('.content-loading').fadeIn(250, function() {
    $('#navigation_all , #content-shown').css("height","6600px");
    $('#pics').load('content.html #sofas-bild').animate({opacity:1},250);
    $('#content-shown').load('content.html #sofas', function() {
    $('.content-loading').fadeOut(250, function() {

        $('#content-shown').animate({opacity:1},250);

    });
    });
    });
    });
            });
            });


</script>
```

before that, i got .click(function() { instead of .live....